# How do I hide an "entry" in the taskbar but keeping the window of the application open and visible?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

How do I hide an "running application entry" (for a lack of a better word) in the taskbar but keeping the window of the application open and visible? I don't mind if the application moves the entry into the notification area ("system tray"). This (and similar question) has already have been asked here:

- [How can I hide an application from the Windows taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/43206/how-can-i-hide-an-application-from-the-windows-taskbar)
- [How to hide a taskbar entry but keep the window form?](https://superuser.com/questions/54284/how-to-hide-a-taskbar-entry-but-keep-the-window-form/167213#167213)
- [How to lock/hide the tabs on the taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1122690/how-to-lock-hide-the-tabs-on-the-taskbar)
- [Hide application task from taskbar but keep window visible in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/846482/hide-application-task-from-taskbar-but-keep-window-visible-in-windows-7)

But none of those solutions worked on my system (either the window needed to be minimized or the software didn't work with Windows 7 at all). Is there another solution or did anyone get any of those solutions to work with Windows 7?